# Saving a web page with embedded video as mht file

Tags: video, mht

Such internet browsers like Internet Explorer and Opera can save web pages as a single mht file.

Assume I have a web page with a `<video>` tag and a video located in the same directory. Is it possible to save this page as a mht file which would contain the video?

I tried to do that, but the resulting mht file contains only html code and pictures.

Comment: I think it depends on where the video is hosted!

Comment: @DaveRook Opera supports the Ogg/Theora/Vorbis format, it can play it but doesn't save.

Comment: Then you've answered your question have you not? Even if you could save the video, if it's referenced externally the webpage will still point to that external resource!

Comment: The video source is refenced just like any image source using the `src` attribute. I don't see any difference.

Comment: yes, but most graphic files are local, maybe saved under the Images folder. If I were to host videos on my server, I'd host them on a different server and embed or reference the external server

Comment: I want to create a simple example. I have one html file, one picture and one video file. They all are located in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Though Opera and Internet Explorer do not include video when you save a web-page as a mht file, it is still possible to add it manually.

I've manually inserted a Base64 code of the video file and a corresponding header to my mht file and Opera opened it without any problem.